# In Verilog, is begin-end block really sequential ? Stratified event queue model doesn't include any such concept

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, hdl

I can understand that in a begin-end block delays are addressed sequentially i.e. they are relative to previous statement. But does it mean that the begin-end block is sequential with respect to execution sequence aswell?

```
integer a;
initial
begin
   a = 1;          // statement_1
   $display(a);    // statement_2
   a = 2;          // statement_3
end
```

Since statified event queue model will put all of the above 3 statements in the Active queue of #0 timestamp. How can we assure sequential execution?

Comment: Only whole procedural blocks (and continuous assignments) are used in scheduling. Whatever is inside of them is executed sequentially.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering "How can we assure sequential execution?"
Within a begin-end block, the following applies.

IEEE Std 1364-2005 section 11.4.1 Determinism

"This standard guarantees a certain scheduling order:
**Statements within a begin-end block** shall be executed in the order in which they appear in that begin-end block.

Execution of statements in a particular begin-end block can be suspended in
favor of other processes in the model; however, in no case shall the statements in a begin-end
block be executed in any order other than that in which they appear in the source."

The posted code should always print 1.

For this snip, all 4 simulators on EDA Playground print 1

```
module tb ();
integer a;
initial
begin
   a = 1;          // statement_1
   $display(a);    // statement_2
   a = 2;          // statement_3
end
endmodule
```

https://www.edaplayground.com/x/6W3Q